# UICollectionView not showing all items

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I am develop in Xamarin.iOs using MVVMCross to databind ObservableCollection to a MvxCollectionViewSource and the items are displayed in a UICollectionView. When setting the items to the ObservableCollection not all of them are shown in the UICollectionView. For instance if I set 10 items to the collection view only 7 of them are shown. Any idea why this could happen?

Comment: Same is happening to me but without using MVVMCross and placing a const item array (item[]) as the items source, so I think it's not MVVMCross' fault but some kind of _wheezy-buggy-stuff_ on the UICollectionViewSource implementation of Xamarin.

Comment: Yes, not sure if I was doing something wrong but I ended up using a UITableView instead

Answer (score 6):

I've had this same problem ONLY in iOS 8.0 but no in iOS 9.0, and @JordiVilaplana answer gave me a hint about the solution.

The problem seems to be the `estimatedItemSize` property of `UICollectionViewController`. **Removing** that line solved the problem.

In fact, that property is only useful if cells heigh is calculated dynamically, as stated by documentation:

> Providing an estimated cell size can improve the performance of the
>   collection view when the cells adjust their size dynamically.
>   Specifying an estimate value lets the collection view defer some of
>   the calculations needed to determine the actual size of its content.
>   Specifically, cells that are not onscreen are assumed to be the
>   estimated height.

Otherwise, if your cells are all the same size take the documentation advice:

> If all of your cells are the same height, use the itemSize property,
>   instead of this property, to specify the cell size instead.

And avoid that problem :)

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into this problem recently and I found out this happens when I set `estimatedItemSize` to `UICollectionViewFlowLayoutAutomaticSize`, if I change it to a random non-zero size i.e `CGSize(width: 1, height: 1)` then the problem is solved and I can still keep the self-sizing UICollectionViewCell.

Answer (score 1):

Finally got it, hope it helps you if you are still stuck with that.

If you have set the `EstimatedItemSize` to your `UICollectionView.CollectionViewLayout` in your code, just **DON'T**, delete that line.

At least, it worked to me.

Have luck! :)

Answer (score 1):

There's a nice way if you're initializing UICollectionView with UICollectionViewFlowLayout:

```
  UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
  layout.estimatedItemSize = CGSizeMake(1, 1);
  layout.itemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayoutAutomaticSize;
  self.collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero collectionViewLayout:layout];
```

Answer (score -1):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if let collFlowLayout = self.mycollecton.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
        collFlowLayout.estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize
    }
}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: 1, height: 1)
    }
}
```